# Log is not generating when testcases run through ant build in selenium webdriver

Tags: logging, ant, selenium-webdriver

Log is not generating when testcases run through ant build in selenium webdriver, But if same test cases run through normally testng then the log is working fine. Please provide some solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <target name="testngRun">
        <taskdef classpathref="classpath" resource="testngtasks"/>
        <testng classpathref="classpath" haltOnfailure="false" outputDir="${testNGreport}">   <!-- Are you adding this property? -->
            <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/>
        </testng>
     </target>
```

will allow you to store your results at specific location.
And if, you want to store you results in standard format (test-output)
just replcae above line with:

```
 <testng classpathref="classpath" haltOnfailure="false" outputDir="test-output">
```